# Can't create button in sandbox

Tags: paypal

Follow the title.
I'm already have PayPal developer account.
when i in the click application -> sandbox account -> click sandbox sits 
I'm already log in but when i try to create button, the web server will direct to real 
papal website. and gave me real buy now button. i just want try buy now button in sandbox,
please help, and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with the launch of the new developer/sandbox site.  As a workaround, when it directs you to the live side just change the live your to that of the sandbox.  So if it directs you to https://www.paypal.com/webscr, you would just need to change it to the following format https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr.  You could also create a non hosted clear text button from your PayPal account, and then just modify the HTML code to point to the sandbox.  You would just change the URL in the button code to point from the live site to the sandbox, and you would just change the business variable and set it to the email address of your sandbox account.

Answer (score 14):

Apparently, the URL for creating test buttons within the sandbox is this:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/c2/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_button-management

Comment: Can you please add some information from the link right here, in your answer?

Comment: I got this to work after removing /c2 from the URL in this answer: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/websrc?cmd=_button-management

Comment: It took me to login, after login it took me to an error. If this happens, just come back here and click the link again and it will take you to the correct place. Thanks Alonso :)

Comment: If this link changes or doesn't work you can click "Profile" in the upper right, and then "Profile and Settings" in the dropdown, and then "My Selling Tools" on the left and then finally "Update" on the "Paypal Buttons" item under "Selling online".

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem..

when i click the "create payment buttons for your website" it redirects to this link [www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/standard-integration](http://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/standard-integration) which is live paypal site. your test account does not exist there so you can not do the rest with the sandbox test account..

i solved it the follwing way..

after redirect to above link... you can edit the link.

put "sandbox." in the link. The edited link will be [www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/standard-integration](http://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/standard-integration)

now you can create your customize button.. the generated HTML will be something like this

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
      <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="5GW6UJKLK47R6">
      <input type="image"   src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
      <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```